# How to bypass "resolved" url on "npm clean-install" when having multiple private registries?

Tags: node.js, npm, continuous-integration, artifactory

How can we bypass "resolved" url when running `npm clean-install` using (node 16, npm >=7)?

**Problem:**
We have an internal private registry so package-lock.json will refer to the internal url. When we then try running builds in GitHub/Azure it tries to resolve the private registry from `package-lock.json` instead of our "build registry", which it can't, and times out after 5 minutes.

I thought that "npm ci" was supposed to fall back to the registries in `.npmrc` and then to `registry.npmjs.org` if it couldn't fetch from the URL in `package-lock.json`. It just sits there (in silence, no logs) and timeouts. It used to ignore the resolved field in `npm <7` and then it got progressively stricter for each npm version.

Right now I only see three solutions:

1. Rebuild all `package-lock.json` in our project with `--omit-package-lock-resolve` flag. But that's not going to be consistent over time...
2. Have our build scripts pre-process the `package-lock.json` and set the resolved field to empty.
3. Don't use `clean-install`, making builds non-reproducible and less compliant.

**Why:**
This is a common enterprise standard way of doing things, but it feels like a lot of things in the node ecosystem doesn't take these real-life organizational needs into account. Where did this obsession with hardcoded URLs all over the place came from? In large organization, these things are usually injected by operations/internal IT, behind proxies, using internal "office URLs" and similar.

Here is an example of the same issue: https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/2004

Comment: This reads like a purely NodeJS-specific issue and not GitHub Actions or Artifactory. You might want to remove the unnecessary tags. Thanks!

Comment: I understand. But the issue has been reported a lot in the context of GitHub actions and organizations with private Artifactory registries. So the idea was that people with that kind of setup probably have experienced the same issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by nuking all `resolved` entries. Not sure this is "good practice" but it works.

```
jq 'walk(if type == "object" then with_entries(select(.key | test("resolved") | not)) else . end)' \
package-lock.json > package-lock.nuke.json \
&& cp package-lock.nuke.json package-lock.json
```